# is this haml documentation incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

from the [haml doc](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html) it says

> If a single value is specified and it
>   evaluates to false it is ignored;
>   otherwise it gets converted to a
>   string. For example:

```
.item{:class => @item.is_empty? && "empty"}
```

> could render as either of:

```
class="item"
class="item empty"
```

But this doesn't make sense to me. Since the `item.is_empty?` is what gets evaluated to true or false, should the correct output be...

```
class="empty"
class="item empty"
```

Comment: No, the documentation is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@item.is_empty? && "empty"
```

Here, if `@item` is empty, `.is_empty?` returns `true`, so the right-hand operand of the `&&` expression is evaluated. The result of this expression is `"empty"`.
If `@item` is *not* empty, `.is_empty?` returns `false`, the right-hand operand of the `&&` expression is *not* evaluated and the result of the expression is `false`.

So, you'll end up with either of these:

```
.item{ :class => "empty" }
.item{ :class => false }
```

What the HAML documentation is saying is that the second case (*"a single value evaluating to false"*) is being ignored, so it boils down to either of these cases:

```
.item{ :class => "empty" }
.item{ }
```

Which results in either of these:

```
class="item empty"
class="item"
```